# how to define regex (preg_replace) to removes space between number character

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, space

I have string like this:

```
$str = "old iccid : 809831 3245 345 new iccid : 999000 112221"
```

How to define regex in order to remove the space character between number character in PHP, to become this output?

```
$output = "old iccid : 8098313245345 new iccid : 999000112221";
```

i've tried to use this syntax:

```
$output = preg_replace( '/\d[ *]\d/', '', $str);
```

but didn't work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$output = preg_replace('/(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)/', '', $str);
```

Comment: This answer is missing its explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The regex engine can traverse the string faster / with fewer steps without the lookbehind.

171 steps: ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/duGHMe/1))

```
/(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)/
```

115 steps ([Demo](https://regex101.com/r/duGHMe/2))

```
/\d\K\s+(?=\d)/
```

You see, while using the lookaround, the regex engine has to look 1 or 2 ways at every occurrence of a space.

By checking for a digit followed by a space, the regex engine ONLY has to look ahead once it has found the qualifying two-character sequence.

In many cases, lookarounds and capture groups endup costing extra "steps", so I prefer to seek out more efficient alternative patterns.

FYI, the `\K` "restarts the full string match".  In other words, it matches then forgets all characters up to the position of the metacharacter.

p.s. You could also use `/\d\K\s+(\d)/` to get the steps down to 106 [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/duGHMe/4) but then you'd need reference the capture group and my personal preference is to avoid that syntax in the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$input = "old iccid : 809831 3245 345 new iccid : 999000 112221"
$output = preg_replace("/(\d)\s+(\d)/", "$1$2", $input);
echo $input . "\n" . $output; //old iccid : 8098313245345 new iccid : 999000112221
```